# Unit testing JSPs in embedded mode

Tags: java, unit-testing, jsp, tomcat, jetty

I am in process of building up a small framework that does unit testing for JSPs. These JSPs have some custom tags, otherwise they are not any special.

Although there are numerous Java unit testing solutions available, I prefer not to use the method where a separate full-blown JSP container is launched, application deployed and results gathered via TCP connection. Typical examples of this case would be Apache Cactus, Selenium, etc. Ideally what I want is to have an embedded solution which is as lightweight as possible (network connection is not being required is a good sign). I have also looked at various mock frameworks but found not a single clean working example when a JSP is compiled/executed during the unit test.

The closest solution I was able to find was using Jetty in embedded mode, or in particular it's ServletTester class, as documented in http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/ServletTester

Unfortunately the above method only works for servlets but has no mention of JSP. I presume there's a way to programatically hook Jasper servlet into it but can't afford spending a week diving into Jetty/Jasper internals just to get the two integrated. I don't mind using any other JSP/Servlet container as long as it is free and flexibly configurable.

I would appreciate if anyone's got a similar setup and willing to share the experience.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example project that run Jettys ServletTester with jsps.

https://github.com/genthaler/jetty-jsp-unit-test-simple/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at HttpUnit - http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/.  It comes bundled with ServletUnit which is an in memory servlet engine that will handle JSPs.  This should usually only be used to test the View portion of a properly factored MVC application or to do some Integration/Acceptance tests.

Business logic should be tested directly from the POJOs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have obviously looked at HttpUnit/ServletUnit during my research, however I couldn't find any clear piece of documentation on how they run JSPs.

Quote from their FAQ: "You will therefore need the Jasper jar in your classpath, along with any on which it depends". 

In other words, this isn't any better than ServletTester example provided by Jetty. Let me know if I'm wrong.